# Proving that The set of limit points is not empty in an infinite group of linear fractional transformation.

Tags: modular-forms

suppose S is an infinite group of linear fractional transformation , show that the set of limit points of S is not empty . I'm studying a modular form course , and I got stuck in this question ,i tried to use the stabilizer ,or to start from SL2(Z) or a discrete group  and then try to generate it , but i can't do it . Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this just because these actions extend to the whole Riemann sphere (which is compact)?

Comment: if we were in SL2(R) and S is not discrete (discontinuous) then the set of limit points is the whole Riemann sphere, but this is not the case , we are not in SL2(R)  @Plinytheill

Comment: So what is your definition of limit point of S?

Comment: z0 is a limit point if there is a sequence of Vn in my group S, and z in the Riemann sphere such that Vn.z tends to z0 as n tends to infinity

Comment: Is this a good definition? We can choose Vn = identity for all n. Then any z in the Riemann sphere is a limit point.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the answer : since S is an infinite group then I can find an infinite sequence Vn.z then it's either bounded or not , if it's bounded then by Bolzano weistrass there exists a subsequence that converges to some z0 so Vnm.z converges to z0 . 
If it's not bounded then Vn.z converges to infinity and then infinity is a limit point so in both cases the set of limit points is not empty .